# How to init Fabric properly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-fabric

There are two different initialisation method shown in the documents:

A) From [here](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/examples/cannonball/index.html#initializing-fabric)

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self(), Answers.self()])
```

B) From [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/answers/install)

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Answers.self])
```

C) This also doesn't make the compiler to complain

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Answers.self()])
```

D) From nowhere

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics(), Answers()])
```

As I know, A and D are identical. But B gets a `Type` array. Which one is the correct one? If they don't differ, how does it work?

Comment: This might help someone. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037060/6407986 Cheers!!!!