# Cannot init both Twitter and Crashlytics with Fabric

Tags: twitter, swift3, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

After migrating to swift 3, the initialisation i used for both crashlytics and twitter (since only one call to fabric is permitted) is not working anymore.

The method given the documentation doesn't work either (it didn't work in swift 2 either by the way).
What is the proper way to initialize this?

I tried all the methods listed here : 
[How to init Fabric properly in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723308/how-to-init-fabric-properly-in-swift) and the init i used before was this :

```
`        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Twitter.self])`
```

But none are working for swift 3.

Error message : `Calling Twitter.start is not supported`

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Twitter.start is different then Twitter.self ; do you have a separate call elsewhere?

Comment: No i don't since it was not required before.
Seems you separated twitter kit from fabric so it will need his own init in appDelegate, which i was aware about that, would've save me some time.

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised then by the error message, but going forward, yes there should be separate inits. For reference for others, here's the blog post that mentions the change: https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2017/Introducing-Twitter-Kit-3.html

Comment: That should be stated in the pod documentation though

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on additional places where it can be made clearer.

Comment: No problem, always happy to save other people some time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIY since twitter kit 3, it is separated from fabric so we now need to instantiate both separatly.

Answer (score 1):

TwitterKit 3+ is no longer part of Fabric

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) 
Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: "key", consumerSecret: "secret")
```

See https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation

you have to add the TwitterKit to the pods as well

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'TwitterKit'
```